# A question on equilateral triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

A point $D$ is on the side $BC$ of an equilateral $\triangle ABC$ such that $DC = \frac{1}{4} BC$ .

Then $AD^2 = ?$

Image I drew...[image: mt1]

Options are $13 CD^2$, $9 AB^2$, $6 CD^2$, $12 BC^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $E$ be the mid point of $BC$.
Then
$$
AE^2 = AB^2-BE^2 = 16-4 = 12$$

$$ AD^2 = AE^2 + ED^2 = 12 + 1^2 = 13$$

$$CD^2 = 1$$

So the answer is $13 CD^2$

Comment: Thanks...for the quick answer